# C program char pointer not displaying character after passing through functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, character

I would love your help in solving this as I have not found a solution in the many examples and videos I found.
I am to create a scrabble game using C programming but for some reason when I pass the character pointer through my functions, the last one to display the scrabble board does not print the letter from my previous function.
Instead of printing the randomly generated character, it prints an empty string.
I have copied the parts of the code that is involved.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int k,j;
char * grid[8][8];

void play(int x, int y, char*c){
  grid[x-1][y-1] = c;
}
void display(){
  for (j=0; j<8; j++){
      for (k=0; k<8; k++){
        if (strcmp(grid[k][j], "")==0){
            printf("%s", grid[k][j]);
        }else{
              printf("%s  ", grid[k][j]);
        }
      }
  }
}
void start(){
  char c[2], *rc;
  c[0] = rand(); 
  rc = &c[0];
  play(rand()%8, rand()%8, rc);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  play(3,7,"a");
  play(4,5,"b");
  start();
  display();
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also include the exact expected result vs actual result.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: This is better.  It is missing the expected vs actual result information, but the code can be analyzed now.

Comment: OK....what happens is that it prints the board with "a" and "b" but the row where the random character was generated and placed shifts instead of shows the character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comment :

```
void start(){
  char c[2], *rc; // c string is local to the function
  c[0] = rand(); 
  rc = &c[0]; // rc points to a string inside the function
  play(rand()%8, rand()%8, rc); // you save an address local to the function
}
```

When start function exits, rc value (= c address) are no more meaningful.
You should allocate memory in the function to have valid and addresses.

Comment: Now it does print the randomly generated letter, but there are symbols behind the printed character.

Comment: As you have 2 chars in your array, be sure to set the 2nd char to 0 to end string. You can have this automatically done if calloc your data.